# Display all products of a sub-category on a new or existing phtml page when clicking on a sub-category from Magento home-page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

I have displayed all parent categories and sub-categories in the home page (left.phtml).

I want each sub-category to be a link which directs to a page where the products of that sub-category should be listed.

Nothing is working right now.

```
   <?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($id); ?>
   <ul
   <?php foreach ($children as $category) { ?>  
   <li>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category->getId())->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a> (<?php echo $category->getProductCount() ?>)</li>
  <?php     } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

When clicking on the sub-category, it gives page not found error. Also nothing is showing in the getProductCount. What link should be given inside `<a href="">` of sub-categories or where should this link be redirected to? From which phtml page the results are displayed.

I found lot of posts and articles regarding display products with categories and sub-categories. But couldn't find a solution for my issue (may be lack of searching skill).

Comment: I just tried your code and it work for me... could you provide me with the the url that this code generate and the actual url for that subcategory. Also you could have use "$category->getUrl()" instead of "Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category->getId())->getUrl()" which is more efficient.

Comment: The code generates the below url: ../catalog/category/view/s/operatory-equip-accessories/id/11/  . I think the url should be 'category/view/operatory-equip-accessories/id/11/' instead of 'catalog/category/view/s/operatory-equip-accessories/id/11/'

Comment: I'm not sure what going on... the url should be '../catalog/category/view/id/11'. Go to Admin -> Catalog -> Mangage Categories.. and lookup the "URL Key" for id 11 ... Also you may want to look up id 11 in Admin -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

Comment: Try appending this path to your base url '/catalog/category/view/id/11' (eg 'www.xyz.com/catalog/category/view/id/11'). If that work then try Mage::getUrl('catalog/category/view', array('id' => $category->getId())) or Mage::getUrl() . "catalog/category/view/id/{$category->getId()}/". Assuming that you are not using SEO friendly url.

Comment: Manually I have given the link...It is not working.. seems something went wrong... any suggestions? For the sub-categories IsAnchor and Is Active is enabled from the admin... Where could be the issue?

Comment: Try creating a new 'test' category and sub categories and add at least 1 product to it. Also does the other site navigation work? Did you lookup id 11 in Admin -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management?

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getUrl('catalog/category/view', array('id', $category->getId()));
```

This code is untested, but I believe it will return the correct url.  If it doesn't, post the url you're seeing.

Comment: It didn't work.Seems some error.Now the sub-categories are not displaying.

Comment: Should be Mage::getUrl('catalog/category/view', array('id', $category->getId())); // add one more closing ')'